# capture data from a cell and paste the value into another cell on a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making this more challenging in my head than it has to be, but since I haven't been using vba or excel recently I'm using this as my excuse. Please don't question the methodology :) as this is only a small step I'm trying eliminate for someone to save some time, until I can redo the entire process. I would do the reverse, but this is an invoice of sorts that they are using....

I'm thinking macro or function is what is needed and not a formula since the data on worksheet 2 will change each month and there is no date I can reference.

What I'd like to do:

I have a cell on worksheet 2 that will change once a month.  I want to place the value of the cell from Worksheet 2 into a cell in worksheet 1 each month that she changes it.

Each month would be represented in column A and the value of the cell from Worksheet 2 during that month needs to be place in column B.

```
Column A         Column B
12/5/2012        $3,459,877.81 
1/8/2013         $9,360,785.62 
2/8/2013        
3/8/2013        
4/8/2013
```

So when she changes worksheet 1 for February the number will populate next to 2/8 and so on.  I was thinking do it when she saves the document, or make it a shortcut she can hit or just scrap it and tell her it's not worth.

Comment: Does the cell on Sheet 1 get changed only once a month in the month she is changing it for? In other words, when February arrives, during that month she changes Sheet1:A1 value and this needs to be entered into Sheet2:B3 next to the February date?

Comment: This actually has an elegant solution which you don't have to store any cell values in other cells. I'll post my mock up below.

Comment: Answer added below. Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving a Cell a name to reference from you can do some neat stuff with the Target parameter passed to the Worksheet_Change function:

```
'Add this function to the sheet that has the cell being
'+changed by the user (Sheet 2)
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    Dim strCellName As String
    strCellName = "ChangeMe"
    'If the cell we changed was the ChangeMeCell
    If Target.Address = Sheet2.Range(strCellName).Address Then
        'Store value
        Dim intLastRow, intValue As Integer
        intValue = Range(strCellName).Value

        'Find the cell in Sheet 1 Column A that matches this month
        intLastRow = Sheet1.Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row
        For Each cl In Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & intLastRow).Cells
            'Ensure cell value is date
            If IsDate(cl.Value) Then

                'If date is today's date
                'Note that Math.Round(<date>, 0 ) essentially removes the time
                '+from any date value so #01/02/03 04:05:06# becomes #01/02/03#
                If Math.Round(cl.Value,0) = Math.Round(Now,0) Then
                    'Update column B's value
                    Sheet1.Range("B" & cl.Row).Value = intValue
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

This assumes you have the sheet layout with the "invoice values" in Sheet1 and the cell being changed in Sheet2. You need to give that cell a name.

Using the cell Name box to the left of the Function bar call the cell that changes "ChangeMe" or anything you wish to change it to, update that cell name in the first line of the function and this function will do all the rest.

[image: Where you find the cell name and change the value to "ChangeMe"]

It is important to note that the dates must be correctly formatted for your systems region. to make sure it is showing the right month - format them into LongDate so you can see them as 08 March 2013 instead of 03/08/13 which may get confusing the longer it goes on. *Speaking as a British programmer, dates are the bane of my life!*

[image: This shows the date format being in long date format and the number value of the B column being displayed with formatted Currency]

**Edit:** I have update the code to compare the dates by the full date minus the time, instead of the previous monthly comparison, if you still need to subtract or add a month to either date value, just use the `DateAdd("m", <date>, <value>)` to add or subtract the month.

**Edit:** [DatePart Function page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/datepart-function-HA001228812.aspx) is a useful resource for those wanting to know more about DatePart()

Comment: this does work, but I want the number that is keyed in.  Not the number that has changed.  At least...that's how I imagined it to work.  I'm thinking this could work for me if I were to use this when she goes to change the current month.  When she does this, the old data that changes can then be placed in the month prior and so on.  I need to test it.

Comment: @blue- How would I get the date to look for the prior month?  or Better Yet for the value to match the Date of the cell that she is changing.  For Example, she is going to change the data in Column B next to the date in Column A.  That data feeds other sheets.  If I can figure out how to grab that data based on that cell I'm good to go.  In essence a vlookup within the macro.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Use dateadd on the Now variable when checking if today's month is the same as the month in column, to go back one month use -1.  If DatePart("m", cl.Value) = DatePart("m", DateAdd("m", -1, Now) ) Then

Comment: I have updated my answer to better match the dates needing to be equal, you can still use DatePart and DateAdd to change the dates as you wish.

Comment: So close!  This works too.  But, now I'm getting picky.  The date she may enter data will be a few days or a week later.  So, on 3/18 she may be doing the invoice for 3/15.  I need it to capture that 3/15 date.  But it updates the number right away and that is perfect!!

Comment: You are very welcome. If you are doing it by week you can use `DatePart("ww",cl.Value) = DatePart("ww", Now)` This will use the week of the year instead. May give you more flexibility. Check out the DatePart API page, it has a lot more options that might help: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/datepart-function-HA001228812.aspx

Comment: Ok, I finally got it to work.  I added a vlookup to the cell so that would change automatically....and presto...it doesn't work.  LOL.  I guess I need to see when the cell in another spreadsheet changes then figure out how to capture the value of the formula in the "ChangeMe" cell.  I really appreciate your help.  This has been quite the lesson.

Comment: Now I'm onto worksheet_calculate v's worksheet change.  Since my "ChangeMe" cell is changing based on a formula.  I'll post my code once  I figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

For my example, I'm using cell `G4` as the one that will be updated by your coworker.  You have to have some way to persist the original value of `G4` in order to tell when it's been changed.  The easy way to do this is to pick some cell that is out of sight of the user and store the number there so you can reference it later.  Here I've chosen cell `AA1`.  The following code must be added specifically to `Sheet2` since it needs to monitor the changed events on that sheet only so it can fire when `G4` is updated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("G4") <> Range("AA1") Then
        Dim lastRow As Long

        Range("AA1") = Range("G4")
        lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Value = Date
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = Range("AA1")

    End If
End Sub
```

Keep in mind that this is a very "quick and dirty" approach for this task, as there are no error handlers or much flexibility in the way it works.

---

**EDIT --**

One other method you could use is referenced here, and can simply check to see if a given cell has changed, without verifying the difference in value.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Not Application.Intersect(Range("G4"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Dim lastRow As Long
        Range("AA1") = Range("G4")
         lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

         Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Value = Date
         Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = Range("AA1")
     End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate your help.  Perhaps I'm doing something wrong to get this to work.  I'm not understanding how putting the value of g4 in aa1 does anything.  When g4 changes so will aa1 if in the AA1 cell I do =G4.  That seems like an extra step.  What I want to do is capture G4 when she changes it. I think this isn't worth the time i'm vesting to be honest.  It really does seem to dirty and has too much chance of error.

Comment: Putting the value in AA1 is so you have a reference to the old value once she changes it.  You don't want to update the page every time something changes *unless* it is changed on G4.  It checks to see if G4 and AA1 are no longer the same, and then runs the code if they are not.  You could do it by [explicitly checking which cells are changed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213612) but I think that's a more complicated way to do it.

Comment: I'm missing how the script will see the change if the cells equal the same and AA1 references G4. I think that's where I am hung up

Comment: I do think the link you sent me might actually work since several cells will change.  I maybe able to add a few more instances for the macro to check before it runs.

Comment: AA1 doesn't reference G4 directly, but if G4 gets changed, then AA1 is reset to match it, but only after it's already executing that `if` block.  Doing it with the AA1 could also allow you to update Sheet1 with the previous value, after she changed it (though you would want to reset AA1 at the end of the code, not the beginning).  I think the linked code would definitely be better if you are going to be monitoring multiple cells for changes.

Comment: if I monitor multiple cells then that lessens the chance for the data being changed to be wrong.  I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Now, I'm able to capture the value from a formula in the cell and place it in a different cell in another worksheet. Here's my final product:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

  Dim strCellName As String
   strCellName = "ChangeMe"
   If Sheets("Application of Moneys").Range(strCellName).Address <> PrevVal Then
    Dim intLastRow, intValue As Long
    intValue = Range(strCellName).Value

   'Find the cell in Sheet 1 Column A that matches this month
    intLastRow = Sheets("Certificate 1").Range("B:B").End(xlDown).Row
    For Each cl In Sheets("Certificate 1").Range("B13:B25" & intLastRow).Cells
        'Ensure cell value is date
        If IsDate(cl.Value) Then

            'If date is today's date
            'Note that Math.Round(<date>, 0 ) essentially removes the time
            '+from any date value so #01/02/03 04:05:06# becomes #01/02/03#
            If DatePart("m", cl.Value) = DatePart("m", Now()) Then
                'Update column B's value
                Sheets("Certificate 1").Range("H" & cl.Row).Value = intValue
            End If
        End If
    Next
End If
End Sub
```